# NamSor parseName return name parts in lower case

Tags: parsing

I use NamSor API method `parsename`. Docs is [here](https://github.com/namsor/namsor-r-sdk2/blob/master/docs/PersonalApi.md#ParseName), API example is [here](https://www.postman.com/api-evangelist/workspace/namsor/request/35240-88f03514-a3bf-49d4-8fc4-17388444f64d). And even with example from documentaion it returns to me first an last name in lower case.

[image]

Is it possible to get parts of the name with capital letters in their places?

I can't capitalize every part of the name because compound names containing prepositions will become incorrect.

[image]